# The argument type 'AnimationController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Listenable'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to create animated custom drawer using complex ui tree(stack, transform and animation). When using animatedcontroller in AnimatedBuilder's animation..i am getting error than animatedcontroller can't be assigned to listenable

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: toggle,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController, //I am getting error here
        builder: (context, _) {
          return


Here is the code i am using....please help me
```

Comment: can you include how you are creating `animationController`

Comment: try using `animationController!`

Comment: Please share the rest of your code.